# Trying to intall GLFW on Linux from Source

Tags: installation, glfw

## Original Question:

I am trying to install GLFW from source on Linux.

I have downloaded and extracted the files from www.glfw.org, and according to the documentation on the Code::Blocks [website](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_GLFW_with_Code::Blocks), all I have to do is enter the directory and type 'make'. I installed cmake and the other dependencies specified inside the readme file.

Typing 'make' gives me the error: No targets specified and no makefile found.

I have an approximate idea as to how cmake works, but probably don't understand it fully. I read the target should be 'x11' or 'x11-install', do I tried 'make x11' and 'make x11-install'.

I also tried a few other things which I had as wild guesses as to what might work. (For example 'make x86_64' but the chances of that working... laughable perhaps.)

So yeah, how do I use cmake to install glfw, on Linux, KUbuntu 13.04... 64 bit...

## Answer:

I have written a write-up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768008/a-quick-writeup-on-how-to-build-and-install-then-compile-and-link-programs-using):

([How to build & install GLFW 3 and use it in a Linux project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768008/a-quick-writeup-on-how-to-build-and-install-then-compile-and-link-programs-using))

Comment: #Answer:

I have written a write-up [here][2]:

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768008/a-quick-writeup-on-how-to-build-and-install-then-compile-and-link-programs-using)


  [1]: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_GLFW_with_Code::Blocks
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768008/a-quick-writeup-on-how-to-build-and-install-then-compile-and-link-programs-using

Comment: #Answer:

I have written a write-up [here][2]:

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768008/a-quick-writeup-on-how-to-build-and-install-then-compile-and-link-programs-using)


  [1]: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_GLFW_with_Code::Blocks
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768008/a-quick-writeup-on-how-to-build-and-install-then-compile-and-link-programs-using