# Missing files in GLFW 3.0.4

Tags: codeblocks, glfw

I'm currently trying to make GLFW work with code blocks but there's a slight problem. I've followed a tutorial (1) for setting it up. The tutorial says that I should copy libglfw.a, libglfwdll.a and glfw.dll file to the respective directories. My problem is that I don't have any of those files, anywhere. I've even tried building with Cmake but that didn't generate any of the specified files.

I do have glfw3.h and glfw3native.h so the header file specified in the tutorial should not be a problem. If I'm wrong about this please say so.

So my question: does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

(1) - http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2011/02/setup-glfw-project-in-codeblock.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a link to download the binaries http://www.glfw.org/download.html (assuming you are using windows)
for a linux compile tutorial: [How to build & install GLFW 3 and use it in a Linux project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768008/how-to-build-install-glfw-3-and-use-it-in-a-linux-project)