# Setup eclipse linker to compile and run GLFW applications - How to?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, linker, glfw

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768008/how-to-build-install-glfw-3-and-use-it-in-a-linux-project) question I was able to make one default cmake compilation for GLFW libraries, compile my [GLFW App](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html) and run; everything works and was made through the terminal since I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits.

I was using this line to compile:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp
```

And this to link:

```
g++ main.o -o main.exec -lGL -lGLU -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi
```

After use those commands I only needed to execute main.exec. However, *I would like to setup eclipse to compile and run this GLFW application*. Include files are already settled on the project but I'm having trouble with my linkers. I was trying to track my libraries (GL, GLU, glfw3....) manually to set the folders but I couldn't find all of them. Does anyone know how could I track the libraries to set them on my linker(Project - Properties - C/C++ Build - Settings - GCC C++ Linker) or could give me some guidelines to solve this situation, please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After try and research for some hours, I found the solution which is pretty easy:

[image]

Instead of add paths to libraries, just add their names as it is in the command line. I still don't know from where the path reference for those libraries are coming (and would be great if someone could explain) but what is most important is that works. After build just run (CTRL + F11) like any other application.