# xcode can't load GLFW which compile by CMake

Tags: xcode, glfw

I follows the [CMake org](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile_guide.html#compile_generate) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768008/how-to-build-install-glfw-3-and-use-it-in-a-linux-project) attempt to load the library but failed.
I have use `make install` put GLFW to /usr/local/include/GLFW/, and then, I add the directory to ***Link Binary With Libraries*** in XCode project.
But `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` said the file not found.
How to load the library? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my first time use cmake, I mess all things. To import the library should add /usr/local/include/ to **Header Search Paths** and add /usr/local/lib/ to **Library Search Paths**, besides, **Link Binary With Libraries** should add `libglfw3.a` in /usr/local/lib/.

import with `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>`