# GLFW window looks weird

Tags: glfw

I followed this guide here from [GLFW's compiling web page](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/compile_guide.html#compile_compile) and the help from this User [How to build and install GLFW3...linux project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768008/how-to-build-install-glfw-3-and-use-it-in-a-linux-project). when I run the simple window from this basic starter template:

```cpp
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, my window looks a bit weird. I was wondering if this was a system thing or if there was a way to change it.
[image]
what I'm trying to go for is a simple window that looks like it wasnt made in 2010.[image]
I looked through the window documentation by GLFW aswell and couldnt find anything that could do what im wanting. [Here](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#window_hints_wnd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit more days of research, I have figured out that it is just the window manager. You can download X servers such as GWSL and VcXsrv.